# Use Alt as Meta key in Carbon Emacs, not Apple Command Key

Tags: macos, emacs, carbon-emacs

Any way to configure [Carbon Emacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html) to use the Option key as a Meta key, rather than the Command key?  I like having a consistent set of keybindings no matter if I am using Emacs in a terminal or Carbon Emacs. Also, I really would like Paste back on command-v.

Comment: I am sympathetic with the vote for moving this to SuperUser, but I note many emacs keybinding questions in the Related sidebar. I'm off to meta to open a question on the topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/what-site-should-host-questions-about-emacs-keybinding

Comment: Hm...  This seemed to be an elisp and emacs customization question for me, which put it here...

Comment: The discussion on the meta questions right now is about even: 3 for SO, 4 for SU. That doesn't add up to a consensus policy in my mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use the alt key for meta, add this to your [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
```

Create the file if needed.

*To get the apple-style copy and paste, add this to the init file:*

```
(mac-key-mode 1)
```

Comment: the file should be ~/.emacs, not ~/.emacs.el. Alternatively, you can also put it in ~/.emacs.d/init.el

Comment: That's great. Thanks! But now how to I make command-v to the paste?

Comment: You are the elisp god. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider using this:

http://emacsformacosx.com/